# Detect Windows 10 s from the browser

Tags: javascript, windows, browser

I have a requirement to redirect a browser to a particular page when the client is running Windows 10 S (specifically "S", just Win 10 isn't sufficient).
The user agent doesn't seem to specify this.

I have found solutions for getting this data via C++ and WMI on the client, but I need to run something like Javascript on a web page and infer if the client is 10 S.

Any help in achieving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not ask your user: are you using Win10s?

Comment: My knee-jerk reaction is: "Why do you need to know this?". I mean - does your technology run differently if it is on Windows S? Because as far as browser is concerned you should **not** care. What am I missing here?

Comment: On a semi-humorous note: if you detect that you are in Edge - it is Windows S!

Comment: The site initiates a download of an application. The application is not in the App Store, and for a variety for a variety of reasons we do not want it in there, so for 10S users we need to redirect them to a informational page explaining what they should do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 S and ran its default browser Edge (any other browser would **have** to be available through Windows Store as it is the only way to run apps on this edition of Windows 10). The `window.navigator.userAgent` in it was super similar to that of Windows 10 Pro except one tiny detail: something called "ServiceUI 11" after the OS info. My guess is that this would be the way for you to find out if the page is running on that particular edition of Windows:

```
function isWindows10S(){
  return window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("ServiceUI") !== -1;
}
```

Tested it on **S** and **Pro** in Edge and Chrome.

When tried in IE 11 though I've got a different result. The string was "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C..." and it was identical between the **S** and **Pro** so looks like that method only works for modern browsers that are based on Gecko :)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm hoping to get a chance to try this out over the weekend.

Comment: Not working on a Windows 10S device we have; the user agent string doesn't have "ServiceUI".

Comment: which browser? I only tried Edge and Chrome and it worked on both for Windows **S**

Comment: This answer no longer works.  "ServiceUI 11" now appears in the userAgent string for Edge running on Windows 10 Pro.  (Observed on my system)

Comment: Damn :( And, of course, there's no official documented workaround, eh?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can use navigator API of window Object which will return you with a string of complete details like *"appCodeName/appVersion number (Platform; Security; OS-or-CPU; Localization; rv: revision-version-number) product/productSub Application-Name Application-Name-version"*

You can check the substring windows exist in the *platformDetail* or not with the specific version.

For e.g. `var platformDetail = window.navigator.userAgent;`

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look this weekend, but I believe the user agent doesn't differentiate between windows 10 and windows 10 S

Comment: You can try node.js to run window cmd. Like this: `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name"`

It returns the window edition you are running your application at.